# COLOR_RGB2GRAY gives none-grayscale image (might be an issue with jupyter-notebook)

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to perform histogram equalization on an image an have 2 issues. First, I need to plot the histogram for the grayscale version of it. When I try to convert the RGB image to grayscale the output is a blue and yellow image. My code goes as follows:

```
img = cv2.imread(r'D:/UNI/Y3/DIA/2K18/lab.jpg') 
RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(RGB_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
plt.title('My picture (before hist. eq.)')
plt.show()
```

This is Jupyter Notebook's output:

[image: This is Jupyter Notebook's output]

But I just realized that if I save if it saves it correctly:

[image]

Since I need to hand in the jupyter doc how could I overcome this issue? Thx!

Second, I perform Histogram equalization but when trying to stack the images horizontally I get the following error form this code:

```
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
res = np.hstack((img,equ))
```

error -> `all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

As far as I can see I didn't touch the images' dimensions at all...

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

The left image should be RGB

Comment: Use a gray colormap instead, like `plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255)` vmin/vmax is to prevent changes in intensity.

Comment: For your second error, `img` is a 3-channel image while `gray` is a single-channel image. For the first error use `plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Fredrik suggested, you can use `plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255)` to get you a grayscale output or you can also convert the Grayscale image to a 3 channel RGB image using `gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`.

Basically the problem is that `gray = cv2.cvtColor(RGB_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)` returns a single channel matrix, where as matplotlib is expecting a 3 channel RGB matrix to be shown, So you can either tell `plt.imshow()` that your input matrix is a single channel matrix using `plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255)` or you can simply convert the single channel matrix to 3 channel matrix and then simply use `plt.imshow(gray)` and everything would work fine.

For the second part of your question where `res = np.hstack((img,equ))` is raising error, it is always helpful to debug the shape of matrices, you want to apply operation upon, You can do that by `print img.shape`, `print equ.shape`. As far as I can see your `img` is a 3-channel matrix (BGR), whereas your `equ` is a single channel matrix (gray), hence error, you would need to convert this `equ` matrix to a 3-channel matrix again using `cv2.cvtColor(equ, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)`.

Comment: spot on !! decent explanation !!

Comment: Got it to work thx! But now I still have another issue: the original image in predominantly blue (as shown in the edited question). I tried putting the colormap to RGB but it says it doesn't exists and gives me a possible list of values, don't know which one to pick for the right correction though :/

Comment: @StefanoPozzi That is because you are reading the image with OpenCV which is of the format BGR. So before saving it convert it to RGB.

Comment: @JeruLuke like this right? `cv2.cvtColor(equ, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) ` if so I seem to get this error `error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor` don't really understand what it means. I tried googleing it and they tell me to change the flag of when I read the image to `1` as so: `img = cv2.imread(r'D:/UNI/Y3/DIA/2K18/lab.jpg', 1)` but doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: @StefanoPozzi I meant it for `img` not `equ`.